# Apple MacBook; SmartBattery; ManufactureDate on macOS Big Sur

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, battery, macos-big-sur

To get detailed information about a Smart Battery of an Apple MacBook is pretty easy:  e.g. via Terminal command:

> $ ioreg -b -w 0 -f -r -c AppleSmartBattery

One element of the result is the "ManufactureDate"; you get an Integer like 19666. A bitfield where the 16 bits represents the date (day, month, year) ...

> /* kBManufactureDateCmd
> */ Date is published in a bitfield per the Smart Battery Data spec rev 1.1  * in section 5.1.26
> */   Bits 0...4 => day (value 1-31; 5 bits)
> */   Bits 5...8 => month (value 1-12; 4 bits)
> */   Bits 9...15 => years since 1980 (value 0-127; 7 bits)
> */

... as described here: [AppleSmartBatteryCommands.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-420.1.20/AppleSmartBatteryManager/AppleSmartBatteryCommands.h?txt) or here [Smart Battery Specifications](http://sbs-forum.org/specs/sbdat110.pdf)

But, now on the macOS Big Sur beta, the result of the request for battery data and the "ManufactureDate" element is not a 5-digit integer (16 bits) anymore, it's a value like: 54091727255090 (46 bits)

Any ideas what changed? Maybe it's just a bug in the Beta? I have an app on the Mac App Store.

Comment: Ooh you've got a problem ... maybe collect a few of these numbers from the same devices and post them here side by side. The new one might just be more precise or from a different reference date or, worst case, encrypted somehow ...

Comment: I don't get ManufactureDate when running this command  on my machine

Comment: Try this command:
ioreg -b -w 0 -f -r -c AppleSmartBattery | grep ManufactureDate

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I've hit the same issue with my app...